# PC needs to reset bios every time it starts

Tags: boot, bios, raid

EVERY TIME I start my custom built PC this appears. I have no clue at all but it may have something to do with a win11 update.
To boot into windows, I'll have to go into bios by F1, load my saved profile, and save&boot.
It seems that my bios was reset.
When I have a memory failure or whatever and my bios resets, it only tells me to plug in my CPU fan because I use water cooling and the pump was plugged into something else. But as you can see in this one it said something about raid, though I've never done anything about raid.(Ignore the keyboard thing)
Any one have any idea  on how to fix this?
[Here is what my boot screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tctXD.jpg)

Comment: Sounds more like you need to replace your CMOS battery

Comment: @Mokubai - Is it the 2032 in there? And why's that? The mobo still runs.

Comment: @Zyleyus The CMOS battery maintains the BIOS settings when the PC is off. A CR2032 is something like $1; the only thing to look out for is the use-by date which will be on the packaging.